# Why does this inner for loop execute when p == 2

Tags: c

I am having a hard time understanding the code below. It is Program 6.10 from *Programming in C* by Kochan. It generates a table of prime numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(void)
{    
    int p, d;
    bool isPrime;`

    // loops through 2 to 50
    for ( p = 2; p <= 50; p++ )
    {
        isPrime = true;

        for ( d = 2; d < p; d++)
            if ( p % d == 0 )
                isPrime = false;

        // prints prime number    
        if ( isPrime != false )
            printf(" %i ", p);
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The preceding code outputs:

> 2  3  5  7  11  13  17  19  23  29  31  37  41  43  47

Can you explain why the inner `for` loop

```
for ( d = 2; d < p; d++)
```

still executes? My understanding is that d = 2 and p = 2; thus, d < p is not true any more.

Comment: The inner loop will execute in every case where d < p. That is true for the other 48 values of p. This code looks like it's working as intended?

Comment: It doesn't execute the loop body when `p==2`. Why do you think it does?

Comment: The inner loop does not execute for `p=2`, `isPrime` remains `true` and 2 is printed.  Indeed, 2 is a prime number !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a false premise.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding; why do you believe the inner loop is executed for `p=2`? As `2` is written to the output, `isPrime` must have been `true` for the first iteration of the outer loop where `p=2`, so the inner loop ist _not_ executed, hence has no opportunity to set `isPrime` to `false`.

Comment: It saddens me to see a programming book teach code like `if ( isPrime != false )` instead of `if (isPrime)`

Comment: Try adding print statements everywhere (printing variables like d, p and isPrime), and follow the flow of the program; you probably see where your misconception stems from.

Answer (score 2):

It's true that `d < p` is not true on the first iteration of the outer loop, but on the next iteration, `p` has the value 3.

The inner `for` loop does not execute when `p` is 2. It does when `p` > 2.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is working as intended.

When `p=2` and `d=2`,

```
for ( d = 2; d < p; d++)
        if ( p % d == 0 )
            isPrime = false;
```

This `for` loop is not executed, `isPrime` is still `True`, and thus it prints `printf(" %i ", p);`

**Note**

If the above `for` loop would have been executed for `p=2` and `d=2`, then

```
if ( p % d == 0 )
    isPrime = false;
```

This condition would have been true, `isPrime` would have been `False`, and the `printf(" %i ", p);` would not have executed.